# Implementing a very simple Bayesian Calibration

Tags: bayesian, python, calibration

I want to understand Bayesian calibration.

I tried to implement a simple Bayesian calibration by constructing a set of truth data and then comparing my model to that data. My understanding of Bayesian calibration is that I should create a set of prior pdfs.

In this case, I created an array for each parameter representing probabilities of different values. I used normal distributions, distributed around the sum of least squares solution to the simulation parameters given the truth data.

I updated these distributions with the formula $P(X|D) = P(D|X)\ P(X)$, and I normalized the distribution after each iteration to account for the missing denominator $P(D)$. After I have my distribution, I make by prediction using the expected value, $\int f(x) P(x) dx$.

My simple example isn't working. Even when my model is capable of perfectly describing the truth (as it is in the settings I show here), the calibrated parameters are incorrect and scattered.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Why am I not getting reasonable pdfs of my uncertain model parameters?

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize as mini
np.random.seed = 1

'''
In this problem I have some high-frequency data that I can't
represent perfectly with my model. Specifically, the "observed"
data is generated as a sum of sin waves with specified amplitudes
of frequencies and the model is sum of sin waves with less frequencies
to specify.
'''

# Each sample is this number of time steps
SAMPLE_TIME = 200

# Number of frequencies in the "observed" data
NUM_TRUTH_FREUQENCIES = 2
TRUE_FF_COEFS = np.random.uniform(0, 1, NUM_TRUTH_FREUQENCIES)

# Create "observed" "truth" Data
samples = 100
TRUE_SIGNALS = []
for _ in range(samples):
    start = np.random.uniform(0, 1e3)
    sample = []
    for t in np.linspace(start, start + 1e4, SAMPLE_TIME):
        sample.append(np.sin(TRUE_FF_COEFS*t).sum())
    TRUE_SIGNALS.append([start, sample])

# Define the low-fidelity model to tune.
NUM_LOWFI_FREQ = 2
def lowfi(LOWFI_FREQ, start):
    signal = []
    for t in np.linspace(start, start + 1e4, SAMPLE_TIME):
        signal.append(np.sin(LOWFI_FREQ * t).sum())
    return np.array(signal)

'''
"vanilla" tuning: minimize the sum of the square of the errors between the models
I could now use these to develop some probabalistic discrepency function between the two models.
I use this to create my prior distributions.
'''
def vanilla_fitness(lowfi_freqs):
    err =  0
    for signal in TRUE_SIGNALS:
        err += np.mean(np.array(lowfi(lowfi_freqs, signal[0])) ** 2.)
    return err
con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.min(1-x), 'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.min(x-1)}
x = mini(vanilla_fitness, np.ones(NUM_LOWFI_FREQ), method='COBYLA', constraints=con)
vanilla_x = x.x
plt.plot(lowfi(x.x, TRUE_SIGNALS[0][0]), label='Model')
plt.plot(TRUE_SIGNALS[0][1], label='Truth')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('Vanilla_Tuning.pdf')
plt.clf()

'''
Baysian Calibration

I define a fitness function for single samples of the signal

For every unkown parameter in the low-fidelity model, I create a prior using
the known bounds.

For each sample, I update the prior according to Bayes rule, P(X) = P(D|X) * P(X)
                 then normalize the probability distribution to account for the 
                 missing denomenator.
'''
def single_fitness(lowfi_freqs, signal_num):
    true_signal = TRUE_SIGNALS[signal_num]
    return np.mean(np.array(lowfi(lowfi_freqs, true_signal[0]) - true_signal[1]))**2

# Create Gaussian priors centered around the some of squares solution
x_prior = []
num_probs = 400
lbounds = 0
ubounds = 1
for ii in range(NUM_LOWFI_FREQ):
    tmp_probs = []
    for val in np.linspace(lbounds, ubounds, num_probs):
        tmp_probs.append(norm.pdf(val, vanilla_x[ii], .5)) # arbitrary sigma
    tmp_probs = np.array(tmp_probs) / np.sum(tmp_probs)
    x_prior.append(tmp_probs)

# Update the priors using the data
x_probs = np.array(x_prior)
for sample in range(samples):
    # p(X) = P(D|X) * P(X)
    x = mini(single_fitness, np.ones(NUM_LOWFI_FREQ), args=(sample,), method='COBYLA', constraints=con)
    x_probs *= np.sum(x_probs[x_probs < x])
    x_probs /= np.sum(x_probs)

def mean_and_std(probs, vals, start):
    mean = np.ones(SAMPLE_TIME)
    std_dev = np.ones(SAMPLE_TIME)
    for jj in range(vals.size):
        print jj
        mean += lowfi(vals[jj], start) * np.prod(probs[:,jj]) * (float(ubounds) - lbounds)/float(num_probs)
    for jj in range(vals.size):
        std_dev += (mean - lowfi(vals[jj],start) * np.prod(probs[:,jj])  * (float(ubounds) - lbounds)/float(num_probs)) ** 2
    return (mean, std_dev)
m, s = mean_and_std(x_probs, vals =  np.linspace(lbounds, ubounds, num_probs), start=TRUE_SIGNALS[0][0])

# this is the plot I would make if it worked. m are values close to one
#     and s are large values
plt.plot(TRUE_SIGNALS[0][1], label='Truth')
plt.plot(m, label='Baysian Calibration')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('Tuned.pdf')
```